# Why is the 'if' condition in my while loop only checked once?

Tags: c#, asp.net, while-loop, sqlexception

I have written code to stop duplication of my Primary Key. I have two tables. One table saves the company details and the other table saves other details. In the table which saves company details, the company registration number is being given as the Primary Key. It should not be duplicated. But the registration number is a Foreign Key to the other table where it can be duplicated as much as it wants.

Here's my Code :

```
public int checkComRegnumberAvailable(string conRegnumber)
{   
    int check = 2;
    int i = 0;

    List<OtherCompany> checklist = getCompanyDetails();

    while (i < checklist.Count)
    { 
        if (checklist[i].RegNumber != conRegnumber)
        {
            check = 0;
            i++;
        }

        else
        {
            check = 1;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return check; 
}
```

Below is the `method` where I execute the SQL statements according to the value of the integer `check` :

```
public void AddCompanyDetails(int NDAid)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        int check = checkComRegnumberAvailable(oc.RegNumber);

        if (check == 0)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO OtherCompanyData (RegNumber,ComName,Country,Address,CoreBusi) values (@regnum,@comname,@country,@address,@corebusi) ", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regnum", oc.RegNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comname", oc.ComName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", oc.Country);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", oc.RegOfficeAddress);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corebusi", oc.CoreBuss);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                AddNDADetails(NDAid);
            }

            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        else if (check == 1)
        {
            AddNDADetails(NDAid);
        }
    }
}
```

On executing the code I get the following exception :

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the point of your check if you call the same add function?

Comment: how did you know that it is checked only once? btw it's meaningless since you return the result of only the last item's condition

Comment: @chouaib I inserted a breakpoint to check the iteration.

Comment: hein... did `i` increase, or it just left the loop after the first iteration? (I believe not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your code to find out if there is a duplicate before adding, but what you are really doing is just verifying that the last element does not match.

Instead, do this:

```
public int checkComRegnumberAvailable(string conRegnumber)
{   
    int i = 0;

    List<OtherCompany> checklist = getCompanyDetails();
    foreach(var company in checklist)
    {
        if(company.RegNumber == conRegnumber)
        { 
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are much better ways to accomplish what you are doing, but this should demonstrate the problem in your current logic.

Comment: How come you can say that OP is checking only the last element?

Comment: His code, as written, will return 1 if the last element matches, and zero if it doesn't.  The value of the intermediate elements have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

That code you have checks every single row and sets `check` to zero or one based on that row.

That means `check` will be set at loop exit based solely on the *last* row.

It needs to be changed to something like this, assuming you want two if the list is empty, one if it's found and zero if not (as appears to be the case from your current code<sup>(a)</sup>):

```
public int checkComRegnumberAvailable (string conRegnumber) {   
    List<OtherCompany> checklist = getCompanyDetails();
    if (checklist.Count == 0)
        return 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < checkList.Count; i++)
        if (checklist[i].RegNumber == conRegnumber)
            return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You need to be careful here since the calling function `AddCompanyDetails` does *not* take an empty list into account. If you want an empty list to be treated identically to "record does not exist" (and it probably should be), get rid of the `if` block that returns `2`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a LOT that should be reconsidered with the code.

First, you're only getting the LAST element from getCompanyDetails() in your result.  Also, why are you returning an int when you should be returning a bool?  Your return of 2 only occurs if the array is empty, and you're not even catching that condition.

First improvement:

```
public int checkComRegnumberAvailable(string conRegnumber)
{       
    List<OtherCompany> checklist = getCompanyDetails();

    foreach (var listItem in checklist)
    { 
        if (listItem.RegNumber == conRegnumber)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Better:

```
public bool checkComRegnumberAvailable(string conRegnumber)
{   
    return !getCompanyDetails().Any(cd => cd.RegNumber.Equals(conRegnumber));       
}
```

And your second method should be:

```
public void AddCompanyDetails(int NDAid)
{
    if (checkComRegnumberAvailable(oc.RegNumber))
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {             
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO OtherCompanyData (RegNumber,ComName,Country,Address,CoreBusi) values (@regnum,@comname,@country,@address,@corebusi) ", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regnum", oc.RegNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comname", oc.ComName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", oc.Country);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", oc.RegOfficeAddress);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corebusi", oc.CoreBuss);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    AddNDADetails(NDAid);        
}
```